# Error running Selenium Grid between Mac Hub and Windows Node

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm having problems when trying to run Selenium Grid using a Mac as the hub and a windows machine as the node.
It worked fine when I opened a different terminal on the Mac (I used the same machine as a hub and node).

My code looks as follows:

```
package WebTests;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Practice{
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl, nodeURL;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
        nodeURL = "http://152.111.16.67:4444/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.XP);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Assert.assertEquals("Welcome: Mercury Tours", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

I downloaded chrome driver on the node machine and ran the following command from the node:

```
    java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://152.111.16.67:4444/wd/hub -port 5566

It connects successfully, but when I run the test I get the following error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: XP, version: }
Command duration or timeout: 113 milliseconds

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at WebTests.Practice.setUp(Practice.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: XP, version: }
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: '02corm-k1ghfh00.za.ds.naspers.com', ip: '197.86.25.251', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:117)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make the following change:

capability.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);